# "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar" setting not remembered

Tags: keyboard, macos, settings, menu-bar

I see no keyboard & character indicator on the menubar panel, and trying to enable *"Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar"* in  *System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab*, that has **no effect** and, after closing and re-opening that settings window, *Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar* is still **NOT** ticked.

[image]

I use more than one keyboard layout and I need to permanently see the active one on the panel, and switch between them from there (at the present I can only switch from shortcut), like in this image I found on the internet:

[image]

Comment: I think that having more than one keyboard on your list in system prefs/keyboard/input sources  should normally automatically put the "flag" menu in your menu bar, but I guess something must be amiss on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this option:

[image]

Comment: I will look up the "Input sources" option as soon as I can. As for the rest more aggressive approach, looking at the link you posted - I am not sure I will try that, it seems recommended for more severe problems (`before you bring it into the Apple Store`) and also some comments there report chilling after effects. I will consider it though. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I have mentioned the character viewer only in response to your comment that two buttons can be shown one in place of the other, I am mainly interested in displaying and switching keyboard layouts on the panel: from the button seen [the image you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYLbp.png), except I use more than one layout, as indicated in update to my question.

Comment: I am almost sure that is the answer!! I cannot test on the spot but I will in a day or so.

Comment: @cipricus if the answer resolves the problem, please remember to select the answer (and we can remove the comments as well)

Comment: as simple as that. i'll look into the 'not remembered' part too